# Geometric interpretation of Ideals in a Prime ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have been told this has a geometric meaning,

$I_j \in F[x_1,...x_n]$ be ideals such that $\cap_1 ^n I_J= P$ for P been a prime ideal, then we know that $P= I_j$ for some j=1,..n

My Understanding
I can prove the statement no problem and what I think I understand is that if we have an affine variety that is an intersection of others then if we can prove that this intersection is equal to a prime ideal then it suffices to look only one of the affine varieties.
Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: One corollary of this is that an algebraic set whose ideal is prime is irreducible, i.e., it can't be written as a union of two strictly smaller closed subsets. This is because $V(I \cap J) = V(I) \cup V(J)$.